# Firebase hosting capture URL segment for HTTP header

Tags: firebase, http-headers, firebase-hosting

I am trying to add a `Link` header indicating canonical URL in my firebase hosting.

[Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#capture-url-segments-for-redirects) are the docs which show how to capture URL segments for the redirect. However, I cannot make it work for the headers.

Here is my code:

```
"headers": [ {
    "source": "**/:url*",
    "headers": [{
        "key": "Link",
        "value": "<https://example.com/:url>; rel=\"canonical\""
    }]
}]
```

This leads to `<https://example.com/:url>` being returned in the link header (i.e. captured segment is not replaced).

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no way to perform parameter replacement in Firebase Hosting headers. The documentation also doesn't seem to hint that this is possible.

It might be worth to [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/), although I've never seen it requested before.

Comment: An alternative would be to manually write each canonical on each page. Doesn't seem like a great option :)